How to resolve network connectivity issues between my Ubuntu VM and Windows host? Ubuntu VM is unable to ping host, but able to ping everything else
I'm having a networking issue with my Ubuntu server VM. My Ubuntu VM is able to ping everything EXCEPT my Windows Host. I've tried disabling the firewall on both sides, assigning a static MAC address, configuring my netplan yaml file. I'm not sure where to go from here.
I've attached pictures of the issue, Host Ip config results, Ubuntu Ip address results, and my netpplan yaml file.
Issue
Windows Host Ip config results
Ubuntu Ip a results
Netplan yaml

I never could get my ubuntu machines to ping either ubuntu systems nor windows systems. Since they can ping the outside world and tech support at TP-Link didn't have a solution and, since my TP-Link router appears to give the same IP address based on MAC address - I've hard codes those IP addresses (192.168.xx.xx) in /etc/hosts.  You won't be able to use the exact same /etc/hosts content on all systems because each has to be 127.0.1.1 on it's own system.  That is, everyone else would know bitwarden as 192.168.10.1 except bitwarden who would know himself as 127.0.1.1 (the local machine).
